# Need help to understand a small piece of a lex/flex hello world example

Tags: yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm a beginner of lex/flex and yacc. I'm now reading a book which gives a hello world example of lex/flex input file, to implement a simple calculator lexer.

The code is here:

```
%{
#include <stdoio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

int
yywrap(void)
{
        return 1;
}
%}
%%
"+"             return ADD;
"-"             return SUB;
"*"             return MUL;
"/"             return DIV;
"\n"    return CR;
([1-9][0-9]*)|0|([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) {
        double temp;
        sscanf(yytext,"%lf",&temp);
        yylval.double_value=temp;
        return DOUBLE_LITERAL;
}
[ \t] ;
.{
        fprintf(stderr, "lexical error.\n");
        exit(1);
}
%%
```

I don't quite understand what does the line `[ \t] ;` do here. Could anybody help me? thx.

Answer (score 2):

The brackets indicate a "character class."  Any character that appears within the brackets is considered a match.  Here we have two characters, space and horizontal tab (`\t`).  These characters are often called "whitespace."

The bare semicolon says "do nothing."

So the rule says, "whenever you see either a space or a tab (a whitespace character), do nothing and get the next character."

Since the input to the lexer might have multiple whitespace characters repeated together, this lexer rule could be applied multiple times. As a simplification, it is common to see a quantifier like `+` (1 or more) or `*` (zero or more) after the character class.  This rule means, "whenever you see one or more whitespace characters, do nothing and get the next character."

```
[ \t]+ ;
```

Comment: Since the lexer does nothing when whitespace pattern is match, could I consider that `[ \t]` and `[ \t]+` behaves nearly the same unless there are some efficiency issues?

Comment: Yes, behaves the same in this lexer. There is a modest difference to the people who read your code, though. [ \t]+ makes it clearer that you want to say "ignore whitespace of any length"; with [ \t], I have to look around to make sure there isn't a longer match that could overrule it for some strings.